# How to share both pdf and text message via whats app in android

Tags: android, pdf

Hi I want to share both text and pdf file at a time in whats app,How it can be done.currently i can share any one of them at a time.

I have tried this but its not working.

```
  Intent share = new Intent();
  share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setType("application/pdf");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My sample image text");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
  share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't send text along with a pdf file, not even from Whatsapp directly.

Comment: I dint get you Shinil

Comment: Try sending a pdf file to someone on Whatsapp along with a text.

Comment: Ya its not working.Thats what my question.

Comment: How can you do something that's not supported by Whatsapp itself?

Answer (score 0):

When you share a PDF document to WhatsApp, the app might not display the associated text along with the document because, WhatsApp
prioritize displaying the PDF document itself and may not show any additional text provided with the intent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).